# org.springframework.core.env.Environment with - Spring Cloud Config Server - external properties file

Tags: spring, git

I've created a personal repository on Git where I have kept my application.properties file.

I've created a cloud config server ('my-config-server') and used the git repository url.

I have bound my spring-boot application that is supposed to access the external properties file with Git repository.

```
@javax.jws.WebService(
              serviceName = "myService",
              portName = "my_service",
              targetNamespace = "urn://vdc.com/xmlmessaging/SD",
              wsdlLocation = "classpath:myService.wsdl",
              endpointInterface = "com.my.service.SDType")

@ConfigurationProperties
public class SDTypeImpl implements SDType {

/*It has various services implementation that use following method**/

private SDObj getObj (BigDecimal value) {
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context =
              new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                      SDTypeImpl.class);
SDObj obj = context.getBean(SDPropertiesUtil.class).getObj(value);
context.close();
return obj;
 }
}
```

Another Class:

```
public class SDPropertiesUtil {

@Autowired
public Environment env;

public SDObj getObj(BigDecimal value) {

 String valueStr = env.getProperty(value.toString());
/*do logic*/ 
}
```

But, I get 'valueStr' as null.

My application starts and the config server on the cloud loads properties file from my git repository.
From the cloud logs, after i pushed my application:

```
PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source:       CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='configClient'], MapPropertySource [name='ssh://blah blah blah.git/application.properties']]]
```

My application is unable to access an external properties file through spring cloud config server.

Comment: So are your properties actually numbers which could fit inside of a `BigDecimal`?

Comment: my properties look like '4.1234 = SSN is not 9 digits' . I also tried making it a String instead of a BigD and then converted it into a BigD but did not work